# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error connecting to SOAP server from PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm making my first attempt to connect to a SOAP server from PHP, and I'm not understanding how to log in and get the data I need.  The service I'm trying to connect to is the Hawley USA service http://hawleyusa.com/thcServices/StoreServices.asmx).  I've been looking at a few posts on how to connect, and I get the basics.  I've verified that I have SOAP enabled in my PHP, and I'm just trying to get an inventory list.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
$wsdl_path = "http://hawleyusa.com/thcServices/StoreServices.asmx?WSDL";

$login_id = 'mylogin_id';
$password = 'mypassword';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_path);

try {
  echo "<pre>\n";
  print($client->InventoryList(array("LoginID" => $login_id, "Password" => $password)));
  echo "\n";
}
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
  echo $exception;      
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get this error:

```
SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in /Users/steve/Sites/mysite/hawley_client.php:12
```

When debugging, I can see the $client instance initiated, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Second question: Am I passing the user ID and password correctly?

Thanks.

**Update**: I threw in $client->__getLastRequest, and this is what I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"              xmlns:ns1="http://hawleyusa.com/thcServices/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:InventoryList/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So I can see that I'm  missing my login ID and password. How do I add them to my InventoryList call?

Comment: As of 2017/06/09, the WSDL is not available and the question is incomplete...

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." typically means a parameter is wrong/missing in the SOAP-request. Be sure to check not only the <soapenv:body> but also the <soapenv:header> (this was the problem in my case).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're close. Looking at the WSDL the InventoryList method takes an object called "request". Modify your call line slightly:

```
$client->InventoryList(array("request" => array("LoginId" => $login_id, "Password" => $password));
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that before, but I must have done something wrong.  Anyway, that gets me closer, but now I get this error:  

    Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /Users/steve/Sites/mysite/hawley_client.php on line 15

Line 15 is this line, BTW.  Looking at the headers, the info is being sent properly now.

Comment: Major facepalm here:  I was using print() with an object.  Changed to var_dump, and it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it's not the same case but it also gives the same error if you don't specify empty strings in fields you don't need to use, taken from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?755549-SOAP-XML-Object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object

Comment: In my case this was the error. I had to provide an empty string on optional fields.

Answer (score 0):

I my case the problem was in typo:

In given docs the filed name was `documentShipmentAddress` (and I was using this)

but in wdsl (schema) was:

`shipmentAddress`

So that could be the problem with this error message.
I have changed the field name to `shipmentAddress` and it solved the problem.