# Moving from cURL Soap to Soap Client in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to use PHP Soap but am really struggling. I can build and send the following via cURL but have no idea how to build using SoapClient.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:auc="http://xxxxxxx.com/APOnline" xmlns:get="http://xxxxxxx.com/APOnline/GMData">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <auc:GMData>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <auc:args>
        <get:Authentication>
           <auc:PartnerId>XXXXXXX</auc:PartnerId>
           <auc:UserName>XXXXXXX</auc:UserName>
           <auc:Password>XXXXXXX</auc:Password>
        </get:Authentication>
        <get:ProjectIdentification>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <auc:Organization></auc:Organization>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <auc:Project></auc:Project>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <auc:ProjectId>1111111</auc:ProjectId>
        </get:ProjectIdentification>
        <get:Timestamp>0</get:Timestamp>
     </auc:args>
  </auc:GMData>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to get it back as an array so I can loop through data. Any help on how to build this with SoapVars or just complex arrays would save me days. From what I see, I can't send authentication via headers so that's where I start getting stuck.

Lastly, in my cURL I pass the following headers:

```
 $headers = array(
                "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                "Accept: text/xml",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Pragma: no-cache",
                "SOAPAction: http://xxxxxxxx.com/APOnline/GMData", 
                "Content-length: ".strlen($postXML),
            );
```

I've tried:

```
 $soapURL = "https://xxxxxx.com/Webservices/DataExchange?wsdl" ;
 $soapParameters = Array('PartnerID' => "xxxx", 'UserName' => "xxxx", 'Password' => "xxxx") ;
 $soapFunction = "GMData" ;

 $soapClient = new SoapClient($soapURL);
 $soapResult = $soapClient->GMData($soapParameters);
 var_dump($soapResult);
```

The error I get is: Fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in /var/www/cron-gg-update.php:35 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('GMData...', Array) #1 /var/www/cron-gg-update.php(35): SoapClient->GMData(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/cron-gg-update.php on line 35

Does anyone have sample code I could try? I'm struggling with how to build the array (I think).

Comment: I feel your pain, but hang in there. What have you tried so far, with `SoapClient`? Can you show some code and the errors you got?

Comment: I added my SoapClient logic above. Certainly not proud of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally sorted it out. I just needed to keep trying.

```
 $soapURL = "https://xxxxx.com/Webservices/DataExchange?wsdl" ;
 $sc = new SoapClient($soapURL);
 $Authentication = array("PartnerId"=>"xxxx","UserName"=>"xxxx","Password"=>"xxxx");
 $ProjectIdentification  = array("ProjectId"=>INT);
 $res = $sc->GMData(array("args"=>array("Authentication"=>$Authentication,"ProjectIdentification"=>$ProjectIdentification)));
```

I was missing the "args" object. It just took a better structured array. Found help on this post ["Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error connecting to SOAP server from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541663/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error-connecting-to-soap)